# ListView doesn't show progressbar when the data loaded

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar

When I start activity with ListView it start to load some information from the Internet and after apply adapter, but during loading ListVIew doesn't show me a ProgressBar ring. When I trying to use SherlockListActivity instead ListView I have same problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/comments"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

```
public class CommentsActivity extends SherlockActivity{

@InjectView(R.id.comments) ListView mCommentsListView;

private String mPostId;
private CommentsAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.comment_activivty);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mPostId = intent.getStringExtra("POST_ID");
    LC lc = new LC();
    lc.execute(mPostId);
}

public void setupAdapter(){
    mAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(this);
    mCommentsListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private class LC extends LoadComments{

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //setup adapter after loading comments
        setupAdapter();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: there is no automatic ProgressDialog inside AsyncTask , did you define and show a ProgressBar yourself?

Comment: Do it like this,
       @Override
       protected Void OnPreExecute(){
}

Comment: Use Progressdialog in AsyncTask or progressbar for showing your progress 
you can also use requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);   update your UI in onpPreExecute() and onPostExecute()

Comment: It seems, I understand my mistake. Simply when I used ListFragment it was automatically and I thought that in ListView it also will be automatically too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ProgressBar` to your layout file:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Inject the `ProgressBar` in your activity:

```
@InjectView(R.id.progress_bar) ProgressBar mProgressBar;
```

Now you have to hide it when the adapter is set:

```
public void setupAdapter(){ 
    mAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(this);
    mCommentsListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,
            @Override
       protected Void OnPreExecute(){

```
   ProgressDialog prgDialog  = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    prgDialog.setTitle("Loading");
    prgDialog.setMessage("please wait")
    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
    prgDialog.show();
```

}

on post Execute

private class LC extends LoadComments{

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    //setup adapter after loading comments
```

prgDialog.dismiss();

```
    setupAdapter();
}
```

}